# Flash player 12+ in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

The version of flash player installed in my ubuntu is 11.2.xxx

Adobe says this is the last version they are going to produce for the Linux operating system and they're not going to release further versions for Linux.

Is it possible to use the flash player ppapi plugin that chrome uses in firefox so that the latest version can be used in ubuntu?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: karel the version is 11.2 using flashplugin installer

Comment: @zipuk - since you have used one of the answers in the duplicate here, I assume you are now acknowledging that this is indeed a duplicate - thus I've linked the two and cleaned up the trailing answer.